# Blender python, what design pattern the Operator class is designed

Tags: python

I'm new to Python scripting, and is confused with the design pattern it's used so I do not quite understand how this class works, here is a code example,

```
class HelloWorldOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello World")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

From the execute() function, how this function is called by Blender and where this 'self' and 'context' comes from remains a mysterious, it has to be somewhere in Blender to call this function.
To sum up a bit, the user defines the real function (the function to be follow a predefined pattern, the function name pattern, the return pattern etc.), then being called by Blender, what design pattern this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HelloWorldOperator` derives from the `bpy.types.Operator` base-class.

The `self` variable is a Pythonic class pattern, it is similar to `this` in C++ like languages. The class variables declared in the class header, e.g. `bl_idname` and `bl_lable`, are shared across all instances of the class. The `self` dictionary contains the per-instance variables and is always the first argument in a Python class method. It is automatically supplied on method calls.

The `context` comes from the Blender environment and contains pointers to the active object, collection, GUI mode and other things.

Classes deriving from `bpy.types.Operator` are high-level functions designed to be used as GUI callback functions. As such they only return GUI status.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, where I do not understand is "to be used as GUI callback functions", is there any pure Python implementation of such pattern I can refer to, so I can have an intuitive   understanding of how this call back is called

Comment: Have you read https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html?